bun .env file dont change
I am writing a discord bot with this. I changed the token value in my .env file, but it still has the same value. The new value is not updated.
DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN="value1" -> old
DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN="value2" -> new
.env file
client.login(Bun.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);

use this
package.json
"scripts": 
   { 
     "run": "bun run src/index.ts", 
     "dev": "bun --watch src/index.ts" 
   },

bun run dev 

my code dont update value2 always use value1
macos m1
bun run env

As I write this, the value 1 is written in DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN. How to delete it and update it?

Do you mean while your code is running? Envvars are set at process time

Yes, the code works by taking the old value. use value1

You’ll have to restart the process manually or use a watch file mechanism for that file

I solved it this way
unset DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN

deleted DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN
